# body width 100% of page not screen

Tags: css, image, background, width

I have a background image in the body of my page set to bottom right. But when the content within the page stretches beyond the screen the background image stops at the edge of the screen instead of where the actual content ends.

Here's the relevant css:

```
html, body {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    font-family : arial, sans-serif;
    background-color : #15242d;
    height: 100%;height:auto;
    min-width: 100%;width:auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #959595;
}

body {
    background-image : url(images/body_bkg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position:right bottom;
}
```

Whats the best way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't already have one, you need to wrap the content of your website in a containing `div` which will expand to the size of the content. Then you need to apply the background image to that `div`, instead of putting it on the `body`.

Comment: I think he's after a smaller image that sits at the bottom right of the content rather than the screen.

Comment: Cool. Not worth a -1 and I'm interested to see what you come up with as I couldn't suss it out in my quick 1 minute attempt.

Comment: Thanks for that - much better to advise than to instantly downvote. I obviously just got the wrong end of the stick with OP's question.